# How to show dynamic model content on click of each list view items in oracle apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I am new to oracle apex. I have below tables.

```
QUESTIONS

ID  SUMMARY    DESCRIPTION
1   FAQ 1      Test 1 Summary
2   FAQ 2      Test 2 Summary
3   FAQ 3      Test 3 Summary

QUESTIONS_ANSWER

Id  ques_id  answer
1   1        Question 1 ans goes here
2   2        Question 2 ans goes here 
3   3        Question 3 ans goes here
```

I have requirement to show all records from table QUESTIONS in list view on home page. So I used Type as ListView and below sql query

```
select ID,
       SUMMARY,
       DESCRIPTION
  from QUESTIONS
```

Now I want to show respective answer from table QUESTIONS_ANSWER in model / page on click of each list items

How to do it in oracle apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a "Link Target" in for your List View.

- Create a report on QUESTIONS_ANSWER on another page (lets assume page 2) and a page item P2_QUES_ID (assuming `QUES_ID` is the foreign key on `QUESTIONS_ANSWER` to `QUESTIONS`).
- Set the query to

```
SELECT 
    answer 
  FROM 
    question_answer
WHERE 
    ques_id = :P2_QUES_ID
```

- On the page with the list view, set the link target to page 2 with item  P2_QUES_ID to value `&ID.`